# Marshal.Copy In Java

Tags: c#, java, jna

I'm trying to convert some C# code to java using JNA, and I'm stuck on this last function.

In C# it's known as

```
Marshal.Copy
```

This is what I tried so far

```
byte[] string = new byte[tSecDec.SECItemLen];
Pointer ptr = new Memory(string.length);
ptr.read(tSecDec.SECItemData, string, 0, tSecDec.SECItemLen);
System.out.println(Native.toString(string));
```

But it didn't work because I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Bounds exceeds available space : size=7, offset=419439024
at com.sun.jna.Memory.boundsCheck(Memory.java:186)
at com.sun.jna.Memory.read(Memory.java:203)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're allocating `tSecData.SECItemLen-1` bytes, and yet you're asking to copy `tSecDec.SECItemLen` bytes.  As the error message indicates, the requested copy bounds exceeds the available (allocated) space.

A) Allocate the full size, don't decrease by one.

B) Use `Native.toString(byte[])` to convert the byte array into a Java `String`.

**EDIT**

The first argument to `Pointer.read()` is an offset.  For the memory you allocated, if it's anything other than zero, combined with a length of `tSecDec.SECItemLen` you are going to exceed your allocated memory's boundary (since it was allocated with a length of `tSecDec.SECItemLen`).

That code is bogus anyway - you're reading a string out of newly-allocated memory, which at best will give you an empty string (if the memory is zeroed).

Comment: The -1 was just a test, didn't mean to post it edited the thread with the current version